# Convert to Requests from Selenium Find Element by XPath

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests

I was using Selenium Webdriver to extract a price from a website using "Find Element by XPath" and then converting it to text. Now I need to switch to using Requests, instead of Selenium, and it seems that I am having multiple problems.

Can someone help me convert this code from into Requests format?

```
listprice = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='title price']")
price = listprice.text
print(price)
```

I tried using the method mentioned below by QHarr, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `xpath` has nothing to do with `requests` but with `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that element is present in requests response

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get(url) # < insert your url. Headers may be required.
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.select_one('span[class="title price"]').text
print(price)
```